# How does GPUImageScreenBlendFilter work?

Tags: java, android, bitmapimage

I am working on a project that requires a group of effects.

And I don't understand. Please explain for me!

```
public static final String SCREEN_BLEND_FRAGMENT_SHADER = "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
        " varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;\n" +
        "\n" +
        " uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n" +
        " uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;\n" +
        " \n" +
        " void main()\n" +
        " {\n" +
        "     mediump vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);\n" +
        "     mediump vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);\n" +
        "     mediump vec4 whiteColor = vec4(1.0);\n" +
        "     gl_FragColor = whiteColor - ((whiteColor - textureColor2) * (whiteColor - textureColor));\n" +
        " }";
```

Comment: Please clearly state your question as to what you don't understand and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i don't understand statements.
Ex: varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
        " varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2 
I don't know how it used